# Repeatation of block of Html if html structure not in loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of product on mypage each product is having a enquiry button on it.
By clicking enquiry button bootstrap pop up opens.

I want that form to work for every product with product id of each product
I have achieved this by putting bootstrap pop up model in loop

my Question is. Instead of repeation blok of bootstrap pop up model , instead of keeping popup html in loop,is it possible to achieve this with function  and keeping popup html outside loop ?

```
<?php if(isset($ser_gal)){
           $gal_count =1;
           foreach($ser_gal as $s){?>
           <div class="element">
                  <div class="tz-inner" >
                <div class="tz-image-item"> <img alt="" src="<?php echo URL;?>gallery/thumbs/thumb_<?php echo $s->IMAGE_PATH    ; ?>"> </div>
                <h6><?php echo $s->interior_cat;?></h6>
                <hr />
                <div class="cl"></div>
                <?php echo $s->title;?>
                <div align="center" ><a href="#" class="btn_enq" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $gal_count;?>" data-title="Feedback">Enquiry</a></div>
              </div>
                </div>

            <!--form--> 
            <div class="bs-example"> 
            <div id="myModal<?php echo $gal_count;?>" class="modal fade">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Enquiry</h4>
                  </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control texttrans_none" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Mobile No</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Product</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                      </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                        </form>
                  </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
                </div>
          </div>
            <!----> 
          <?php $gal_count++;} }?>
```